# async.series and javascript variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I think there's a fundamental disconnect in my understanding.  I've been reading up on callbacks and I've searched for why the following might not work, but I may be looking in the wrong places.  I have the following code:

```
  users = []
  async.series [
    () ->
      userClient.smembers "users", (err, list) ->
        async.each list, (item, cb) ->
          userClient.hgetall item, (err, user) ->
            users.push user
        , (err) ->
          console.log err            
    , 
    () -> 
      console.log "test"
      console.log users
    ]
```

The console.log "test" doesn't seem to be printing, and I've tried a lot of different iterations of the code, but once it gets outside of the inner most loop (users.push user), I can't retrieve the value for users.  I end up with an empty array [].  Anyone have any insight or can perhaps point out where I've gone wrong in my thinking?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each function is asynchronous, it cannot know automatically when to progress to the next  step in the series. Each series function take a callback as an argument that you need to call.

```
(doneCallback) ->
  userClient.smembers "users", (err, list) ->
    async.each list, (item, cb) ->
      userClient.hgetall item, (err, user) ->
        users.push user

        // You also need to call 'cb' here.
        cb();
    , (err) ->
      console.log err

      // Add this to go to the next step after.
      doneCallback(err)
```

Also depepending on what you are using `users` for, you may want to use [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) instead of [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) to simplify the code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  Still wrapping my head around the asynchronous stuff, but this has helped!